# Beautiful Soup Not Finding HTML Element

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

We are attempting to find the html element "c_pagination_list" on the following Forever21 page: http://www.forever21.com/Product/Category.aspx?br=21men&category=mens-tops. However, when we use BeautifulSoup to get this element, it returns empty or None. Below are the following ways we attempted to get this element:

```
numberArray = soup.findAll('div', attrs={ 'class' : 'c_pagination_list'})

number = soup.find('div', class_='c_pagination_list')

number = soup.select('div.c_pagination_list')
```

Can anyone help explain what the proper syntax for getting this information or what we're missing here?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
numberArray = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'c_pagination_list'})
```

I think this should work.